# Getting the pretty value of a Select field in Node twig template

Tags: theming, entities, 8

I would like to get the pretty value from a field in my content.

Here is the structure of the select box field when I add a content :

```
00|Ground
01|Apartment
02|House / Cottage
03|Business premises
06|Attachments
```

In my node--*content-type*.html.twig, when I call the field with :

```
content.field_*machine_name*.value
```

It display the key of the selection (00, 01, 02,...). I would like to have Apartment, House / Cottage, ....

When I call just this :

```
content.field_*machine_name*
```

It display the pretty value but wrapped in a div that I don't want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> When I call just this :
>
> ```
> content.field_*machine_name*
> ```
>
> It display the pretty value but wrapped in a div that I don't want.

This is the correct way, you should if possible render a field in node twigs like this.

The div, that you don't want, is probably in the field twig, that gets invoked by using `{{ content.field_*machine_name* }}`.

You have to put a copy of `field.html.twig` in your theme and name it:

`field--field_*machine_name*.html.twig`

And look there for the div.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the "raw" filter:

```
{{ content.field_examplefield|raw }}
```

Also, make sure to hide label at

/admin/structure/types/manage/example_content_type/display